Comedy where a monster is still alive on a vehicle in the end
I'm looking to determine the name of a movie I saw on TV many years ago. I do not believe that this was made as a TV movie. It was a comedy monster movie where either one or two main characters fight off the monsters and win. The monster(s) were humanoid and I think were classic monsters (vampire, mummy, etc.)
The twist at the end is that one of the monsters is alive in the back of the vehicle as he or they drive/ride off. I'm pretty sure that this vehicle may not have been a car. I think it was a horse drawn vehicle, but not entirely positive. You but don't see the hero/heroes attacked or know if they survive.
I actually watched The Fearless Vampire Killers and three Abbott and Costello movies (...meet the Mummy, Frankenstein and The Invisible Man) trying to find the answer, and it's neither of them. I believe that this movie would be older than the early 1980s and most likely in black and white.

Showing that the monster is still alive in the end is unfortunately a very common trope in horror\monster movies. Do you remember anything else about the plot? The nature\appearance of the monster? Other specific scenes?

Hi and thanks for the response. The monster(s) were humanoid and I think we're classic monsters (vampire, mummy, etc.) Agreed that using the monsters being alive is a common twist - this went a bit further and it was in the back of the vehicle that the "hero" was leaving in and alive. I'll give some thought to any other characteristics of the movie and post as well. First visit to this site, so thank you for your help and patience.

Maybe Interview with the Vampire?

Might have been "Waxwork" a 1988 movie. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waxwork_(film)
I actually watched the sequel first, early to mid '90s movie, pretty different, follows straight on from the original. More comedic than number one too.

Can you give any info why this might be it? Especially considering the OP thinks it's older than 80's and in B&W? Is the ending similar for instance? Could you edit your answer to include some more information? You mention it might be Waxwork, but only seem to talk about the sequel.

Is it perhaps The Fearless Vampire Killers? 
It is a comedy horror film, it ends with the heroes leaving on a horse drawn sled together with the rescued maiden - who unfortunatey was already bitten and turned into a vampire.

Hi and thanks for the feedback. This isn't it. I actually watched this and three Abbott and Costello movies (...meet the Mummy, Frankenstein and The Invisible Man) trying to find the answer. The movie in question leaves more up to the imagination - you know the monster is alive but don't see the hero/heroes attacked or know if they survive. I think it may have been a wagon, more than a sled.
